# loop through data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to change the orders of data frames using for loop but it doesn't work. My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':1, 'b':2}, index=1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':3, 'c':4}, index=1)
for df in [df1, df2]:
    df = df.loc[:, df.columns.tolist()[::-1]]
```

Then the order of columns of df1 and df2 is not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of chain assignment with list comprehension i.e

```
df1,df2 = [i.loc[:,i.columns[::-1]] for i in [df1,df2]]

print(df1)
   b  a
1  2  1

print(df2)
  c
1  4
```

Comment: You can add this `df1.reindex(columns=df1.columns[::-1])`

Comment: @Wen it can be simply `df.loc[:,::-1]`

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** In my answer I am trying to build up to show that using a dictionary to store the datafrmes is the best way for a general case. If you are looking to mutate the original dataframe variables, @Bharath answer is the way to go.

---

**Answer**:

The code doesn't work because you are not assigning back to the list of dataframes. Here's how to fix that:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':1, 'b':2}, index=[1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':3, 'c':4}, index=[1])
l = [df1, df2]
for i, df in enumerate(l):
     l[i] = df.loc[:, df.columns.tolist()[::-1]]
```

so the difference, is that I iterate with `enumerate` to get the dataframe and it's index in the list, then I assign the changed dataframe to the original position in the list.

---

**execution details:**

Before apply the change:

```
In [28]: for i in l:
    ...:     print(i.head())
    ...:     
   a  b
1  1  2
   c
1  4

In [29]: for i, df in enumerate(l):
    ...:          l[i] = df.loc[:, df.columns.tolist()[::-1]]
    ...:
```

After applying the change:

```
In [30]: for i in l:
    ...:     print(i.head())
    ...:     
   b  a
1  2  1
   c
1  4
```

---

**Improvement proposal:**

It's better to use a dictionary as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
d= {}
d['df1'] = pd.DataFrame({'a':1, 'b':2}, index=[1])
d['df2'] = pd.DataFrame({'c':3, 'c':4}, index=[1])

for i,df in d.items():
     d[i] = df.loc[:, df.columns.tolist()[::-1]]
```

Then you will be able to reference your dataframes from the dictionary. For instance `d['df1']`

Comment: it doesn't mutate `df1`, try it

Comment: It mutates the copies in the list... I am not trying to mutate the original variables..

Comment: But isn't this what the OP wants?

Comment: OP want to mutate the original variables

Comment: @EdChum I was building up to propose using a dictionary for easier manipulation of dataframes. It's one way of the solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse columns and values:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':1, 'b': 2}, index=[1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'c':3, 'c': 4}, index=[1])
print('before')
print(df1)
for df in [df1, df2]:
    df.values[:,:] = df.values[:, ::-1]
    df.columns = df.columns[::-1]

print('after')
print(df1)
df1
```

Output:

```
before
   a  b
1  1  2
after
   b  a
1  2  1
```